# Iterate through relational arrays using bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Please can someone advice with an example how to achieve the below written in bash.

For each data center I will like to run a function on every vm for that datacentred.

dc=(aws, azure)

aws=("aws-vm1" "aws-vm2" "aws-vm3" .. . "aws-vm10")

azure=("azure-vm1" "azure-vm2" "azure-vm3" . . . "azure-vm10")

This should be scalable as the DC and VM can grow.

Will this be best done using switch statement

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The bash code will be

```
dc=(aws azure)    # no commas for array initialization
aws=(             # can use newlines for readability
    aws-vm1 
    aws-vm2 
    aws-vm3 
    ... 
    aws-vm10
)
azure=(azure-vm1 azure-vm2 azure-vm3 ... azure-vm10)

for provider in "${dc[@]}"; do
    declare -n p=$provider           # set a "nameref" for ease of use
    for vm in "${p[@]}"; do
        echo do something with $provider vm $vm
    done
done
```

this outputs

```
do something with aws vm aws-vm1
do something with aws vm aws-vm2
do something with aws vm aws-vm3
do something with aws vm ...
do something with aws vm aws-vm10
do something with azure vm azure-vm1
do something with azure vm azure-vm2
do something with azure vm azure-vm3
do something with azure vm ...
do something with azure vm azure-vm10
```

Comment: It's crucial do use quotes as shown

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for advice on how to do basic programming, regardless if this is bash or not. If I understand your question, you want to know how to iterate over multiple lists.

Use a [`for`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) loop.

```
for a in dc; do
  for b in aws; do
     # does work for all AWS instances in the array
  done

  for c in azure; do
     # does work for all instances in the azure array
  done
done
```